# how to change group ownership in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a question about changing group ownership when I did a long listing of a username home root ls `-ld ~` and the output came something like this `drwx------. 6 prince prince` and I was wondering if I have a group called music, how would I change group ownership to music? so the result would something like this prince music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step, you should first find out the available group names by running the command `groups`

Considering a case where "music" is one of the available groups, you can change ownership of root recursively by executing the following command:

`sudo chown -R prince:music ~`

Answer (score 1):

You could change ownership of the folder using `chown`

`sudo chown -R username:group directory`

In your case, it would be using 
`sudo chown -R prince:music directory`